# Umbraco backoffice - Models Builder/Generate Models is missing

Tags: umbraco, umbraco8

Running locally, logged in as admin, the "Models Builder" section is just not there.  My co-worder, when running it locally with the same login sees it just fine:

[image]

But I am just missing that section for whatever reason.

Here is my Web.Config

```
<add key="Umbraco.ModelsBuilder.Enable" value="true"/>
<add key="Umbraco.ModelsBuilder.ModelsMode" value="AppData"/>
```

What am I missing?  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a different web browser? It could be the Umbraco js files are being cached on your machine, so try clearing your temporary internet files.
Also, press F12 to open the developer tools in your web browser and check if there are any errors logged in the console.